# JQuery UI Sortable irregular drop behaviour at end of list of items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following test code that seems to be just about working

However, if I want to drag and drop one of the DIV items right at the end, sometimes it drops at the end and sometimes it drops in the last but one position.  Am I missing something obvious?

I have tried various things like the tolerance but doesnt seem to make a lot of difference.

```js
 $(function(){

  $('#widgets1').sortable(
  
  {
    update: function (event, ui) { 
   var productOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
   console.log(productOrder);
    },

    placeholder: "target1",
    
    helper:'clone',

    start: function(e, ui) {
     $(ui.helper).addClass('dragon');
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
     $(ui.helper).removeClass('dragon');
    },
    
    change: function(event, ui) {
   ui.placeholder.css({visibility: 'visible', border : '1px solid yellow'});
   },
    
    tolerance: "intersect"
  
  }
  
  
  );

 })
```

```css
#widgets1{ border:1px solid blue; margin-left:50px;margin-top:20px; position:relative; }

 h3{ font-size:2.0em; }

 .dragon{
   border:8px dotted black!important;
 }

 .box1{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   float:left!important;
 }

 .box1a{
   border-color:blue;
 }
 .box1b{
   border-color:red;
 }
 .box1c{
   border-color:green;
 }
 .box1d{
   border-color:orange;
 }
 .box1e{
   border-color:cyan;
 }

 .target1{
   
   border:2px solid purple!important;
   background-color:black!important;
   /*z-index:999999!important;*/
   color:yellow!important;
   opacity:0.3!important;
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   
 }

 .holder1{
   border:1px solid red;
   width: 500px !important;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>test</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
 </head>
 <body>
   <div style="float:left;clear:both" id="widgets1" class="holder1">

 <div id="11" style="position: relative;" class="sortable box1 box1a">
   <h3>
   ROW 1
   </h3>
  </div>

 <div id="12" style="position: relative;" class="sortable box1 box1b">
   <h3>
   ROW 2
   </h3>
  </div>

 <div id="13" style="position: relative;" class="sortable box1 box1c">
   <h3>
   ROW 3
   </h3>
  </div>

 <div id="14" style="position: relative;" class="sortable box1 box1d">
   <h3>
   ROW 4
   </h3>
  </div>

 <div id="20" style="position: relative;" class="sortable box1 box1e">
   <h3>
   ROW 5
   </h3>
  </div>

 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is that your versions of jQuery are pretty dated. Both of those were released in 2011...

https://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/

http://blog.jqueryui.com/2011/08/jquery-ui-1-8-16/

Is it possible for you to use newer versions? Also, I see .box1 has a css float property. In my experience, float can have some unintended effects with jQuery UI.